# How to interrupt a while loop with a function

Tags: python, discord.py

ok so this is probably so easy but i am trying to find a away for the past 4 hours and i can't find it. So i have this discord bot where is like a stopwatch, you enter a command and the stopwatch start (i'm using a while loop that each time sleep for 1 second because i find it easier). Then with another command the stopwatch should stop, but since the while loop started it can't exit to find the boolean that stop it.
(I'M STILL USING DISCORD PY 1.7.3 BECAUSE I HAVE NOT CHANGED THE CODE YET TO 2.0!!!)

Here is the code

```
from discord.ext import commands
from time import sleep
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!', intents=intents)

isCounting = False

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot logged on")
    print("-----------------")





@client.command()
async def start(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send("Stopwatch Started")
    isCounting = True
    seconds = 0
    while isCounting == True:
        seconds = seconds + 1
        sleep(1)
        print(seconds)

@client.command()
async def stop(ctx, arg):
        turnoAttivo = False
        await ctx.send("The stopwatch Stopped")
```

I don't get any errors because the while loop is running, so i don't know how should i do this.
Thank you.

Comment: Use `asyncio.sleep()` instead of `time.sleep()`

Comment: Maybe you should try using some synchronization primitives like mutexes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html

Comment: Besides what is said, `global` versus `local`. Read up [here](https://www.simplilearn.com/tutorials/python-tutorial/global-variable-in-python) for example...

Comment: If you want a stopwatch, you could save the times the commands where called and compare the start and end times instead of manually counting

Comment: You can save [`ctx.message.created_at`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.created_at) to see when the command was called, then compare the two against each other.

Comment: yeah, you need a place where you put some status in, and read that status and check it, you know most databases can help, or you write it on local files or in the memory of the machine where you run the code, I know keyword global in python, you should check that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stop the loop with a condition, you can use this construction :

```
is_counting = True

while is_counting:
    do_some_stuff()
    if condition:
        is_counting = False
```

Thus you set the flag to False by the condition and it interrupts the loop.
Also there is a option to use `break` like this:

```
while True:
    do_some_stuff()
    break
```

Comment: The problem is the condition is in another function that i can't call until i exit the loop. Is there a way to set the function that can be used everywhere?

Comment: Like when the command stop kicks in the "isCounting" become false, but no inside the loop.